# 'toString()' showing undefined

Tags: javascript, express, tostring

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
var fetchUrl = require("fetch").fetchUrl;
var wordsCounter = require("word-counting");
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json())



app.post("/game", (req, res) => {
 const data= req.body;
 console.log(data.website)
 fetchUrl(`${data.website}`,  (error, meta, body) =>{
 let answer = wordsCounter(body.toString(), { isHtml: true }).wordsCount;
 console.log(answer)
 res.send({answer}); 
  });
}); 
app.listen(6000, () => {
 console.log("Server in action!");
});
```

I was trying to convert the HTML body to string so as to count the number of words but it's showing TypeError, Why is it so?

Comment: In which line do you get the TypeError? Can you show the full stack trace?

Comment: Can you link the documentation for `var fetchUrl = require("fetch").fetchUrl;`

Comment: Did you use the URL with `HTTP/HTTPS`?